# Remove attribute from layered filter based on parent category

Tags: magento, filter, catalog

On my magento site, each product sits in two parent categories.  Basically, each product is in both "Shop by Product" and "Shop by Device", and then of course there are child categories in side of those.  For example, case for a tablet will appear in Shop by Device > iPad, as well as Shop by Product > Tablet Cases.

Each product also has an attribute for "compatibility" and "product type."  I would like to remove the "compatibility" filter from layered filters on the catalog page when shopping under "Shop by Device," and remove the "product type" filter when shopping under "Shop by Product"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

put the code in start of  layer.phtml in catalog/layer/view.phtml

```
$yes=0;
if(Mage::registry('current_catgeory')){
    if(Mage::registry('current_catgeory')->getParentId()==$catid):
    $yes=1
    endif;
}
```

then filter showing position add

```
<?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

change

```
<?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
        if($yes==1 &&  $_filter->getName()==$Attributelabel){
            //hide
            }
            else{
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
        }
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I receive the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\iHomeCases\site1\app\design\frontend\default\ihome\template\catalog\layer\view.phtml on line 37`

Comment: I'm not sure if this notified you or not, linking your name again.